# Scipy - Stats - Meaning of parameters for probability distributions

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

Scipy [docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.expon.html#scipy.stats.expon) give the distribution form used by exponential as:

```
expon.pdf(x) = lambda * exp(- lambda*x)
```

However the fit function takes :

```
fit(data, loc=0, scale=1)
```

And the rvs function takes:

```
rvs(loc=0, scale=1, size=1)
```

Question 1:
Why the extraneous location variable? I know that exponentials are just specific forms of a more general distribution (gamma) but why include the uneeded information? Even gamma doesn't have a location parameter.

Question 2:
Is the out put of the fit(...) in the same order as the input variable. By that I mean
If I do :

```
t = fit([....]) , t will have the form t[0], t[1]
```

Should I interpret t[0] as the shape and t[1](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.expon.html#scipy.stats.expon) as the scale.

Does this hold for all the distributions?

What about for gamma :

```
fit(data, a, loc=0, scale=1)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Every univariate probability distribution, no matter what its usual formulation, can be extended to include a location and scale parameter. Sometimes, this entails extending the support of the distribution from just the positive/non-negative reals to the whole real number line with just a PDF value of 0 when below the `loc` value. `scipy.stats` does this to move all of the handling of `loc` and `scale` to a common method shared by all distributions. It has been suggested to remove this, and make distributions like `gamma` `loc`-less to follow their canonical formulations. However, it turns out that some people do actually use "shifted gamma" distributions with nonzero `loc` parameters to model the sizes of sunspots, if I remember correctly, and the current behavior of `scipy.stats` was perfect for them. So we're keeping it.
2. The output of the `fit()` method is a tuple of the form `(shape0, shape1, ..., shapeN, loc, scale)` if there are `N` shape parameters. For a normal distribution, which has no shape parameters, it will return just `(loc, scale)`. For a gamma distribution, which has one, it will return `(shape, loc, scale)`. Multiple shape parameters will be in the same order that you give to every other method on the distribution. [This holds for all distributions.](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.rv_continuous.fit.html#scipy.stats.rv_continuous.fit)

Comment: you should note also that if you need to fit your function correctly (without the extraneous parameter loc for the exponential) you should give a parameter floc (fixed location) equal to 0 (the value of the location you want to fix).

Comment: Quite so! Thank you for mentioning that.